# Checking if user input matches HashMap value

Tags: java

I've been trying to get this quiz to work for a while now. Everything seems to be working up until I try to count how many questions the user got right. It seems as though the "correct" variable isn't getting added onto when it should be. It always displays 0.

```
public class PresidentQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer correct = 0;
        Map<Integer, String> president1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        president1.put(35, "Kennedy");
        president1.put(36, "Johnson");
        president1.put(37, "Nixon");
        president1.put(38, "Ford");
        president1.put(39, "Carter");
        president1.put(40, "Reagan");
        president1.put(41, "George Bush");
        president1.put(42, "Clinton");
        president1.put(43, "George W Bush");
        president1.put(44, "Obama");
        System.out.println("Size of map: " + president1.size());

        Map<Integer, String> president2 = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(president1); 
        Set set1 = president2.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator1 = set1.iterator();
        while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)iterator1.next();
             System.out.print("President #" + me.getKey() + ": ");
             System.out.println(me.getValue());
            }
        HashSet<Integer> randint = new HashSet<Integer>();
        while(randint.size() < 5) {
            randint.add((int) (Math.random() * ((44 - 35) + 1) + 35));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Presidents Quiz");
        System.out.println();
        String pres = null;
        Iterator<Integer> iterator2 = randint.iterator();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Who was president #" + iterator2.next() + "?");
            pres = input.next();
        }
        while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
            String name = president1.get(iterator2.next());
            if (name == pres) {
                correct += 1;
            }
        }
        // Print correct score
        System.out.println("Your score was " + correct);
        System.out.println();
        // Want to sort names in alphabetical order
        System.out.println("Here are the last 10 presidents in alphabetical order:");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant compare strings using `==`. You must use `equals()`. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)